# compiling on linux server (u2) warning long long

Tags: c++, linux, long-integer

While I compile on eclipse (3.8) I have no warnings and errors, but while compiling on server "u2" the following warnings appears on the screen:

```
In file included from gtest-all.cc:39:
gtest.h:17459:47: warning: anonymous variadic macros were introduced in C99
In file included from gtest-all.cc:39:
gtest.h:2756: warning: ISO C++ 1998 does not support 'long long'
gtest.h:3001: warning: ISO C++ 1998 does not support 'long long'
gtest.h:3002: warning: ISO C++ 1998 does not support 'long long'
gtest-all.cc: In function 'bool testing::internal::ParseNaturalNumber 
(const   std::string&, Integer*)':
gtest-all.cc:1424: warning: ISO C++ 1998 does not support 'long long'
```

The warning appears on a line in gtest.h referring to long long.
This is one of my Classes:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "MovieSystem.h"
#include "Menu.h"
class TestMenu: public::testing::Test {
protected:
Menu menu;

public:
virtual void SetUp(){
}
virtual void TearDown(){
}
public:
TestMenu() :
    menu(){}
};

/***********************************************
 * test the printing of the function show menu *
 ***********************************************/
TEST_F(TestMenu, ShowMenuCheck){
string ExpectedOut = "choose an option: \n"
        "1. Create new movie. \n"
        "2. Create new cast member. \n"
        "3. Add a cast member to a movie. \n"
        "4. Add genre to a movie. \n"
        "5. Define sort type to cast members of a movie. \n"
        "6. Print cast of a movie. \n"
        "7. Print a movie. \n"
        "8. Add movies. \n"
        "9. Print all movies of a cast member. \n"
        "10. Remove a movie. \n"
        "11. Remove a cast member. \n"
        "12. Remove a cast member from a movie. \n"
        "13. Print all movies. \n"
        "14. Print all cast members. \n";
testing::internal::CaptureStdout();
menu.showMenu();
std::string ActualOut = testing::internal::GetCapturedStdout();
EXPECT_STREQ(ExpectedOut.c_str(), ActualOut.c_str());
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? 
PLEASE ..

Comment: The compiler is too old.

Comment: Probably because Zohar Argov died in 1987. He never knew a newer compiler than gcc 0.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're compiling with the "pedantic" flag. Turn it off if you don't really need it.